# Rails | connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I host a Postgres 12 instance using docker on my local machine.
It can be reached using username `postgres` and password `postgres` and the database is `test`. I tested that the instance is running and connections are possible using the provided credentials with a differenct client (e.g. TablePlus).

But a brand new Ruby on Rails project throws the following error at me:
`connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?`

my `database.yaml` file looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  database: test

test:
  <<: *default
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  database: test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV["DB_DATABASE"] %>
  username: <%= ENV["DB_USERNAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] %>
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

(I'm on an M1 Mac, btw)

Comment: Can you share your `docker-compose.yml` too?

Comment: You nee to give Rails a hostname to connect to.  Try 'localhost' if you don't know of anything else to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the host and port number to connect to the database running on docker.

Add these two lines ...

```
default: &default
  ...
  host: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost') %>
  port: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_PORT', 5432) %>
```

If you look at a fresh database.yml file generated by rails, you will find these lines...

```
  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432
```

[Domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) works when processes run on the same host OS. Since the database process is on docker which is technically another host, server needs database's TCP [Socket address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) to communicate.